# Asus G751J won't turn on after suddenly shutdown itself

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, laptop-repair

So yesterday I was working on my company's laptop when my personal laptop (asus g751j)  just died with no warning (I wasn't doing anything on it).
It suddenly shut down. I tried to turn it back on but it's dead.
The LEDs show no reaction.

The laptop's battery has been dead for years and never recharges but I left it in the laptop anyway since I don't use the laptop outside the desk.

So I tried to remove the battery (and it wasn't easy in this laptop model) and use the plug directly because I read somewhere that a bad battery may prevent the laptop from starting but still doesn't turn on. I also tried to leave the power button pressed 40 seconds and then try to use it with the plug.

It could be the power supply? Also, I have a spike protector outlet and it's not that old...

Any ideas on what I should do?

I could try to buy another battery to replace this one but how can I know if it will fix the problem?

Comment: It *could* be the power supply. Do you know anyone who could check it for you?

Comment: no, I would probably have to take it to a shop. You think I could attempt to use another power supply from another laptop or something? What would I have to look for? amperes? excuse my english

Comment: Also  the power suply has a green led

Comment: If you've got another 19.5 V power supply that is rated at about 9 A (or more) and has the correct connector, you could try that. Or maybe better, try this power supply on a different device that works from 19.5 V (half a volt difference either way would be OK too).